# Custom ordering in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Table_id   |   Name   |   Mark  | IDTable
-----------+----------+---------+------------
    1      |   John   |   12    |   NULL
    2      |   Alex   |   15    |   NULL
    3      |   Josh   |   11    |   NULL
    4      |   Merry  |   17    |    2
    5      |   Gary   |   13    |   NULL
    6      |   Jimmy  |   18    |    1
```

I want to sort the table to be like this:

```
Table_id   |   Name   |   Mark  | IDTable
-----------+----------+---------+------------
    1      |   John   |   12    |   NULL
    6      |   Jimmy  |   18    |    1
    2      |   Alex   |   15    |   NULL
    4      |   Merry  |   17    |    2
    3      |   Josh   |   11    |   NULL
    5      |   Gary   |   13    |   NULL
```

I mean, first try to sort by `Table_ID`, BUT if `IDTable` is equal to `Table_id`
show it under that row.

Comment: Is `IDTable` a child of `Table_id`? If so, can you have multiple children? I.e. `Table_id` 1 has a child with a `Table_id` of 6, which also has a child with a `Table_id` of 7, etc, etc.

Comment: @Larnu , yes IDTable is Table_id child, but it only can have one child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your sample data COALESCE would work:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(IDTable, Table_id )
,        IDTable
```

Comment: Might want to add `, IDTable` at the end. That ensures that values with a value of  *`NULL`* will appear at the top, and then the *child* tables.